# Traefik not binding to ports 80 and 443 on node hosts

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, k3s, traefik-ingress

I have a two node cluster in AWS which I set up using K3S v1.21.5+k3s1. I just did a default installation, so I have Traefik as my IngressController which should be binding to ports 80 and 443 on each node. However, checking `netstat` shows that nothing is listening on those ports for either node, and any attempt to connect to running pods from my browser fails.

The interesting thing is, I've tried rebooting the nodes to see if that fixes the issue (it doesn't), and I see that in addition to the normal `svclb-traefik` Daemonset, a second Daemonset gets created called `svclb-traefik-######`:

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system get ds
NAME                             DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
svclb-traefik                    2         2         2       2            2           <none>          21d
svclb-traefik-23fcfc42           2         2         0       2            0           <none>          8m45s
```

Checking that second Daemonset, I see that the pods it's trying to start up are failing because the nodes they are allocated to do not have free ports. This is as expected, since the "real" svclb-traefik appears to have already bound them (at least as far as kubernetes knows). Deleting this second svclb-traefik Daemonset does not solve the problem, and the Daemonset returns with the next reboot.

I've checked the traefik daemonset, the traefik LoadBalancer Service, and all the traefik pods to see what could be wrong, (output from `kubectl describe` is below) but everything looks healthy. What other things should I be looking at?

The Daemonset:

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system describe ds svclb-traefik
Name:           svclb-traefik
Selector:       app=svclb-traefik
Node-Selector:  <none>
Labels:         objectset.rio.cattle.io/hash=f31475152fbf70655d3c016d368e90118938f6ea
                svccontroller.k3s.cattle.io/nodeselector=false
Annotations:    deprecated.daemonset.template.generation: 1
                objectset.rio.cattle.io/applied:
                  H4sIAAAAAAAA/8xUTW/jNhD9K8WcKUWy7EQW0MMiySFoNzFsby+BEVDkKGZNkQI5UmMY+u8FZWftbL6KbQ89ejjz/Oa90dvBRhkJBVxxrK1ZIAED3qg/0HllDRTAm8afdSkwqJG45M...
                objectset.rio.cattle.io/id: svccontroller
                objectset.rio.cattle.io/owner-gvk: /v1, Kind=Service
                objectset.rio.cattle.io/owner-name: traefik
                objectset.rio.cattle.io/owner-namespace: kube-system
Desired Number of Nodes Scheduled: 2
Current Number of Nodes Scheduled: 2
Number of Nodes Scheduled with Up-to-date Pods: 2
Number of Nodes Scheduled with Available Pods: 2
Number of Nodes Misscheduled: 0
Pods Status:  2 Running / 0 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:  app=svclb-traefik
           svccontroller.k3s.cattle.io/svcname=traefik
  Containers:
   lb-port-80:
    Image:      rancher/klipper-lb:v0.2.0
    Port:       80/TCP
    Host Port:  80/TCP
    Environment:
      SRC_PORT:    80
      DEST_PROTO:  TCP
      DEST_PORT:   80
      DEST_IP:     10.43.82.221
    Mounts:        <none>
   lb-port-443:
    Image:      rancher/klipper-lb:v0.2.0
    Port:       443/TCP
    Host Port:  443/TCP
    Environment:
      SRC_PORT:    443
      DEST_PROTO:  TCP
      DEST_PORT:   443
      DEST_IP:     10.43.82.221
    Mounts:        <none>
  Volumes:         <none>
Events:
  Type    Reason            Age   From                  Message
  ----    ------            ----  ----                  -------
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  36m   daemonset-controller  Created pod: svclb-traefik-pjffb
```

The Service:

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system describe svc traefik
Name:                     traefik
Namespace:                kube-system
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/instance=traefik
                          app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                          app.kubernetes.io/name=traefik
                          helm.sh/chart=traefik-9.18.2
Annotations:              meta.helm.sh/release-name: traefik
                          meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: kube-system
Selector:                 app.kubernetes.io/instance=traefik,app.kubernetes.io/name=traefik
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.43.82.221
IPs:                      10.43.82.221
LoadBalancer Ingress:     <node 1 IP>, <node 2 IP>
Port:                     web  80/TCP
TargetPort:               web/TCP
NodePort:                 web  30234/TCP
Endpoints:                10.42.1.116:8000
Port:                     websecure  443/TCP
TargetPort:               websecure/TCP
NodePort:                 websecure  32623/TCP
Endpoints:                10.42.1.116:8443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age   From                Message
  ----    ------                ----  ----                -------
  Normal  EnsuringLoadBalancer  16m   service-controller  Ensuring load balancer
  Normal  AppliedDaemonSet      16m   service-controller  Applied LoadBalancer DaemonSet kube-system/svclb-traefik-23fcfc42
```

One of the "good" pods (from svclb-traefik):

```
Name:         svclb-traefik-pjffb
Namespace:    kube-system
Priority:     0
Node:         <node 1>
Start Time:   Fri, 03 Feb 2023 08:25:09 -0500
Labels:       app=svclb-traefik
              controller-revision-hash=56b6bf6489
              pod-template-generation=1
              svccontroller.k3s.cattle.io/svcname=traefik
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.42.1.96
IPs:
  IP:           10.42.1.96
Controlled By:  DaemonSet/svclb-traefik
Containers:
  lb-port-80:
    Container ID:   containerd://6ae25fd4dea39238f3d222dce1a25e3b01a7fb159cecd3e2684257e91dbfd4d7
    Image:          rancher/klipper-lb:v0.2.0
    Image ID:       docker.io/rancher/klipper-lb@sha256:5ea5f7904c404085ff24541a0e7a2267637af4bcf30fae9b747d871bfcd8a6f7
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      80/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 03 Feb 2023 08:46:33 -0500
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Unknown
      Exit Code:    255
      Started:      Fri, 03 Feb 2023 08:25:10 -0500
      Finished:     Fri, 03 Feb 2023 08:46:05 -0500
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  1
    Environment:
      SRC_PORT:    80
      DEST_PROTO:  TCP
      DEST_PORT:   80
      DEST_IP:     10.43.82.221
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-72smb (ro)
  lb-port-443:
    Container ID:   containerd://b9ba3ec21cbd249f1e03d0f3230af9774ff7208ca56a5623a2b45b595a76889e
    Image:          rancher/klipper-lb:v0.2.0
    Image ID:       docker.io/rancher/klipper-lb@sha256:5ea5f7904c404085ff24541a0e7a2267637af4bcf30fae9b747d871bfcd8a6f7
    Port:           443/TCP
    Host Port:      443/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 03 Feb 2023 08:46:33 -0500
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Unknown
      Exit Code:    255
      Started:      Fri, 03 Feb 2023 08:25:10 -0500
      Finished:     Fri, 03 Feb 2023 08:46:06 -0500
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  1
    Environment:
      SRC_PORT:    443
      DEST_PROTO:  TCP
      DEST_PORT:   443
      DEST_IP:     10.43.82.221
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-72smb (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-72smb:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 CriticalAddonsOnly op=Exists
                             node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/pid-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable:NoSchedule op=Exists
Events:
  Type    Reason          Age   From               Message
  ----    ------          ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Created         17m   kubelet            Created container lb-port-80
  Normal  Started         17m   kubelet            Started container lb-port-80
  Normal  Created         17m   kubelet            Created container lb-port-443
  Normal  Started         17m   kubelet            Started container lb-port-443
```

One of the "bad" pods (from the svclb-traefik-XXXXX Daemonset):

```
Name:           svclb-traefik-23fcfc42-t6jx7
Namespace:      kube-system
Priority:       0
Node:           <none>
Labels:         app=svclb-traefik-23fcfc42
                controller-revision-hash=74f5f855c9
                pod-template-generation=1
                svccontroller.k3s.cattle.io/svcname=traefik
                svccontroller.k3s.cattle.io/svcnamespace=kube-system
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  DaemonSet/svclb-traefik-23fcfc42
Containers:
  lb-tcp-80:
    Image:      rancher/klipper-lb:v0.4.0
    Port:       80/TCP
    Host Port:  80/TCP
    Environment:
      SRC_PORT:    80
      SRC_RANGES:  0.0.0.0/0
      DEST_PROTO:  TCP
      DEST_PORT:   80
      DEST_IPS:    10.43.82.221
    Mounts:        <none>
  lb-tcp-443:
    Image:      rancher/klipper-lb:v0.4.0
    Port:       443/TCP
    Host Port:  443/TCP
    Environment:
      SRC_PORT:    443
      SRC_RANGES:  0.0.0.0/0
      DEST_PROTO:  TCP
      DEST_PORT:   443
      DEST_IPS:    10.43.82.221
    Mounts:        <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False
Volumes:         <none>
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     CriticalAddonsOnly op=Exists
                 node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane:NoSchedule op=Exists
                 node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule op=Exists
                 node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                 node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists
                 node.kubernetes.io/pid-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists
                 node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable:NoSchedule op=Exists
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age   From               Message
  ----     ------            ----  ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  19m   default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't have free ports for the requested pod ports. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
  Warning  FailedScheduling  19m   default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't have free ports for the requested pod ports. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
```

Answer (score 1):

Extremely unsatisfying answer here, but I ended up deleting *both* the "real" `svclb-traefik` and the `svclb-traefik-XXXXX` Daemonsets and rebooting the nodes. On startup, both Daemonsets were recreated (and the `-XXXXX` one was still failing to start it's pods), but I can at least connect to my pods from my browser. I'll update this answer if the problem recurs.